# Hand execution in c, don't understand what index -1 means

Tags: c

I have this code and I am trying to do a hand execution from it but I am not sure what `index - 1` does. Should my result be `1,5,6,8,9` or `1,3,5,6,8` or am I completely wrong?

```
void main() {
    int array[5] = {1,3,4,6,7};
    int index;

    for (index = 1; index < 5; index++) {
    array[index] = array[index - 1] + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think index - 1 does?

Comment: Build a version with debug information. Load it into a debugger. Step through the code, line by line.

Comment: its replacing every term in the array ( except first ) with the previous value + 2. @Marievi no it wont, only accessing `array[4]`

Comment: Sorry guys, did not notice `<` 5. Deleting my comment.

Comment: `index-1`is one less than the current index. So if `index` runs from 1`..4`, then `index-1` would be `0..3`.  As for the final result, you should just run the code to find out.

Comment: @SherylHohman ah okay so your saying that the first index will stay the same at 1 and then for the rest of the array it would go back one so at index 1 it would go back to index 0 and so on. hence my results should be 1,3,5,6,8

Comment: @sam it does not modify index 0, it will write to index 1 the value of index 0 plus 2 (I.e. it writes 3 to index 1). Then it writes to index 2 the value of index 1plus 2 (I.e. 5) so it results in 1,3,5,7,9

Comment: @eckes wait so are you saying it would be 1,3,5, then go to index 3 and write index 2 plus 2 which would be 6 wouldnt it or does it disregard the 4 and uses the new data of 5 so index 3 would be 7?

Comment: It writes 5 to index 2, then reads index 2 value and adds 2 which results in 7 which it writes to index 3

Comment: All but the first value of the array does not matter as they are overwritten

Comment: @eckes ah okay thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*values in array before start loop: 1,3,4,6,7*

The value for index is set at the top of each iteration of the for loop.
So the first time through the loop, `index` is set to represent the value `1`.

- so `index-1` would hold the value `1-1`, or `0`
- so `array[index - 1]` is the same as `array[0]`
- `array[0]` holds the value `1`.
- hence `array[index - 1] + 2` is the same as `1 + 2`, or `3`
- So then, we assign `array[index]` which we know to represent the `array[1]` which *used to hold the value of `3`*, now is assigned to (again) hold the value `3`.

*values in array at end of 1st time through the loop: 1,3,4,6,7*

Now, back up to the top of the loop..
`index` is told to increment itself by `1`
ie: `index` *which was 1*, now represents the number `2`

- so `index-1` would hold the value `2-1`, or `1`.
- so `array[index - 1]` is the same as `array[1]`,
- `array[1]` holds the value `3`
- so `array[index - 1]` + 2, is the equivalent of `3 + 2`, or `5`
- So then, we assign `array[index]` which we know to represent the element `array[2]` (*which used to hold the value of `4`)*, now is assigned to hold the value `5`.

*values in array at end of 2nd time through the loop: 1,3,5,6,7*

etc.

```
array      index  index-1  array[index-1] array[index-1]+2  array[index]
1,3,4,6,7  1      0        1              3                 array[1] = 3
1,3,4,6,7  2      1        3              5                 array[2] = 5
1,3,5,6,7  3      2        5              7                 array[3] = 7
1,3,5,7,7  4      3        7              9                 array[4] = 9
1,3,5,7,9  5      (exits for loop since condition fails)
```

final result: `1 3 5 7 9`

> Also, you can use an 'online c compiler' to test code snippets.

Here's one: [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler)